# Can't think of an OUTER JOIN query for the following database

Tags: sql, outer-join

I have the following database schedules, and I'm struggling to create a query using an OUTER JOIN. Do I have schedules that are good to apply an outer join on?

I tried a lot of things but it mainly showed me the same results as an INNER JOIN.

```
CREATE TABLE CLUB(
cl_id       INT     PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
naam        TEXT                    NOT NULL,
adres       VARCHAR(200)                NOT NULL,
dtm_opricht         TEXT                    NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE STADION(
sta_id      INT     PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
cl_id       INT     REFERENCES CLUB(cl_id),
naam        TEXT                    NOT NULL,
adres       VARCHAR(200)                NOT NULL,
capaciteit          INT                 NOT NULL,
dtm_bouw            TEXT                    NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE HOOFDTRAINER(
ht_id       INT     PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
cl_id       INT     REFERENCES CLUB(cl_id),
naam        TEXT                    NOT NULL,
adres       VARCHAR(200)                NOT NULL,
salaris     REAL                    NOT NULL,
nationaliteit   TEXT                    NOT NULL,
geslacht            TEXT                    NOT NULL,
dtm_geboorte        TEXT                    NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE ASSISTENTTRAINER(
at_id       INT     PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
cl_id       INT     REFERENCES CLUB(cl_id),
ht_id       INT     REFERENCES HOOFDTRAINER(ht_id),
naam        TEXT                    NOT NULL,
adres       VARCHAR(200)                NOT NULL,
salaris     REAL                    NOT NULL,
nationaliteit   TEXT                    NOT NULL,
geslacht            TEXT                    NOT NULL,
dtm_geboorte        TEXT                    NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE SPELER(
sp_id       INT     PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
cl_id       INT     REFERENCES CLUB(cl_id),
ht_id       INT     REFERENCES HOOFDTRAINER(ht_id),
naam        TEXT                    NOT NULL,
adres       VARCHAR(200)                NOT NULL,
salaris     REAL                    NOT NULL,
nationaliteit   TEXT                    NOT NULL,
geslacht            TEXT                    NOT NULL,
dtm_geboorte        TEXT                    NOT NULL,
positie     TEXT                    NOT NULL,
rugnummer           INT                 NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: The point of a OUTER JOIN is that it will still include results if the value of joining column was not found in the joined table. So if this doesn't happen, the results will be the same as an inner join.

Comment: Also, conditions in your WHERE clause can end up excluding some of the results you're looking for.  Make sure you only require conditions on the main table.

Comment: Is it possible one of you could give an example of a query for these tables using an OUTER JOIN? Just to get the idea of it?

Comment: why do you need an outer join? is this a class assignment?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM            speler s
LEFT OUTER JOIN club   c ON c.cl_id=s.cl_id
```

Most of the referencing columns you have are nullable (1 to 0-1 relations), so LEFT JOINs are useful to fetch the referenced data, if it exists, without losing the referencing data if it doesn't.